# Can @Model.Count() count something like a Status Name?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I am attempting to use `@Model.Count()` to count how many current tickets I have with the status Open, Resolved, Pending, etc.. Currently, using `@Model.Count()` counts all my tickets, but I also want it to specifically count certain types of tickets. This is what I have so far in my code.

```html
<!-- Column -->
<div class="col">
    <div class="card card-hover">
        <div class="box p-2 rounded bg-megna text-center">
            <h1 class="font-weight-light text-white">@Model.Count()</h1>
            <h6 class="text-white">Total Tickets</h6>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Column -->
<div class="col">
    <div class="card card-hover">
        <div class="box p-2 rounded bg-primary text-center">
            <h1 class="font-weight-light text-white">@Model.Count()</h1>
            <h6 class="text-white">Open</h6>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Column -->
<div class="col">
    <div class="card card-hover">
        <div class="box p-2 rounded bg-info text-center">
            <h1 class="font-weight-light text-white">1100</h1>
            <h6 class="text-white">In Progress</h6>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        @if (item.TicketStatus.Name == "Open")
        {
            <td><span class="badge py-1 badge-primary">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TicketStatus.Name)</span></td>
        }
        else if (item.TicketStatus.Name == "In Progress")
        {
            <td><span class="badge py-1 badge-info">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TicketStatus.Name)</span></td>
        }
        else if (item.TicketStatus.Name == "Pending")
        {
            <td><span class="badge py-1 badge-warning">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TicketStatus.Name)</span></td>
        }
        else if (item.TicketStatus.Name == "Resolved")
        {
            <td><span class="badge py-1 badge-success">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TicketStatus.Name)</span></td>
        }
        <td><a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id" class="font-weight-medium link">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)</a></td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Project.Name)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OwnerUser.FullName)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Created)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DeveloperUser.FullName)</td>
    </tr>
}
```

So do I need to create a ViewModel to define my ticket statuses so I can then count them? Or is there a simpler way that I am missing. I was thinking I could do something like `@Model.Count(TicketStatus.Name == "Open")` but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try somthing like this

```
@Model.Count(x => x.Name == "open")
```

Comment: Yes this was the solution. I didn't realize I could write a lambda expression.

Comment: I will thank you if you accept this as an answer :)

Comment: Yep I did. I just had to wait for the 6 minute timer.

Answer (score 1):

I have figured it out. You can write lambda expressions inside the parentheses of Model.Count().

So I had this and it worked.

@Model.Count(t => t.TicketStatus.Name == "Open")